# Simplifying inequality $|2x+1|>|x+2|$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this set $E=\{x\in\mathbb R:|2x+1|>|x+2|\}$.

I want to decompose this inequality in something like this:
\begin{align}
|x+1|>0\Leftrightarrow
\end{align}
\begin{array}{col1col2col3col4col5}
x & + & 1 & > & 0\\
-x & - & 1 & > & 0
\end{array}

But I don't what steps to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way out in dealing with inequalities of the form $\vert x \vert > \vert y \vert$ is to square them since $$\vert x \vert > \vert y \vert \iff x^2 > y^2$$
In your case, we get that $$(2x+1)^2 > (x+2)^2$$ Rearranging, we get that $$4x^2 + 4x + 1 > x^2 + 4x + 4 \implies 3x^2 > 3 \implies x^2 > 1 \implies x \in (-\infty,-1) \cup (1, \infty)$$

Comment: I see, but don't we have to do $$\sqrt{(2x+1)^2} > \sqrt{(x+2)^2}$$?